# How can I force `track by` usage in all `ng-repeat`?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, lint, eslint

What can be used to lint the angular html file, for example, make possible to force that developers to use `track by` in all `ng-repeat`in the whole project?

Comment: have you tried htmllint, assume you are only concerned about html files.

Comment: https://github.com/htmllint/htmllint this one?

Comment: yes, and define customized rules.

Comment: This project looks like a baby project, I'm not sure if it's ready to production, and I also not found docs about how to create custom rules.

Comment: here is the project download info: 1,148 downloads in the last day
6,656 downloads in the last week
27,133 downloads in the last month. so why do you think it is a baby project?

Comment: seems good numbers, do you know how to create custom rules? I didn't found documentation.

Comment: you can check https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint/wiki/Usage, near the bottom part:)

Comment: HTMLHint != htmllint.